# How would I call ImageMagick from node JS?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Is it possible to import and call image magick from node js? If so, how would one go about doing it?

**UPDATE:**
I followed the instructions on installing ImageMagick from this [page](https://github.com/elad/node-imagemagick-native) and it says it installed successfully but when I try and call it from the command line I get an error.

```
brew install imagemagick
user:myproject$ imagemagick
bash: imagemagick: command not found
```

[image]

And when I try to install the ImageMagick-native nodejs wrapper I get other errors:

```
> imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install /Users/user/Documents/project/prototypes/project/project/node_modules/imagemagick-native
> node-gyp rebuild

ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
gyp: Call to 'sw_vers | grep 'ProductVersion:' | grep -o '10.[0-9]*'' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/Documents/project/prototypes/project/project/node_modules/imagemagick-native
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN web@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN web@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the imagemagick-native@1.9.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/debug.log
```

Comment: You don't state your OS, but I guess **macOS**? If you `brew install imagemagick` that gives you the command `magick`, not `imagemagick`. Try `magick identify -version` for example. You can see what **homebrew** installed, in terms of files and commands with `brew ls imagemagick`. Sorry I know nothing about `node` but note that the package suggested in an answer is from 2012, i.e. ancient.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes! thank you. i kept checking for `imagemagick`. `magick` is installed. That might be the fix. I'm using 13.0.1. I might have been confused because the NPM module uses `imagemagick`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then , ImageMagick has a npm module. Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

Install in your project by this command : npm install imagemagick
Import in your file : const im = require('imagemagick');
and read documentation about all available functions

Comment: Thank you. I am have followed the instructions from the website (link above) and get some errors. I've added them into my post above.